# Codeigniter, using URL as parameter for query

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am using codeigniter, i am trying to create a page where if the url entered example.com/mobil/bekas/toyota/avanza it shows all used car that has toyota as brand and avanza as model, and if the url entered example.com/mobil/bekas/toyota it shows all used car that has toyota as brand.

Here is my controller :

```
public function bekas($brand_nama,$model_nama='NULL')
        {      
               $this->load->model('listing_model');
               $data['cars'] = $this->listing_model->viewListingByBrandAndModel($brand_nama, $model_nama);
               $this->load->view('product_listing.php', $data);
        }
```

Here is the model :

```
function viewListingByBrandAndModel($brand_nama, $model_nama)
    {

        $this->load->library('pagination');
            $this->load->library('table');
            $config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/mobil/bekas/'.$brand_nama.'/'.$model_nama;
            $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->select('*')
                            ->join('car_list_tbl','car_list_tbl.car_list_ID = user_listing_tbl.car_list_ID')
                            ->join('member_tbl','member_tbl.mID = user_listing_tbl.mID')
                            ->join('model_tbl','model_tbl.model_ID = car_list_tbl.model_ID')
                            ->join('series_tbl','series_tbl.series_ID = car_list_tbl.series_ID')
                            ->join('body_type_tbl','body_type_tbl.body_type_nama = car_list_tbl.body_type_nama')
                            ->join('brand_tbl','brand_tbl.brand_name = car_list_tbl.brand_name')
                            ->where('car_list_tbl.brand_name',$brand_nama)
                            ->like('model_tbl.model_nama', $model_nama)
                            ->where('user_listing_tbl.listing_type','BEKAS')
                            ->get('user_listing_tbl')->num_rows();
            $config['per_page'] = 20;
            $config['num_links'] = 10;
            $config['display_pages'] = TRUE;
            $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
            $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
            $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
            $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
            $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['first_link'] = FALSE;
            $config['last_link'] = FALSE;
            $config['prev_link'] = false;
            $config['next_link'] = false;
            $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left">';
            $config['next_tag_close'] = '</i></a></li>';
            $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right">';
            $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</i></a></li>';
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);

             //Pagination End

            $sql = $this->db->select('*')
                            ->join('car_list_tbl','car_list_tbl.car_list_ID = user_listing_tbl.car_list_ID')
                            ->join('member_tbl','member_tbl.mID = user_listing_tbl.mID')
                            ->join('brand_tbl','brand_tbl.brand_name = car_list_tbl.brand_name')
                            ->join('model_tbl','model_tbl.model_ID = car_list_tbl.model_ID')
                            ->join('series_tbl','series_tbl.series_ID = car_list_tbl.series_ID')
                            ->where('car_list_tbl.brand_name',$brand_nama)
                            ->like('model_tbl.model_nama', $model_nama)
                            ->where('user_listing_tbl.listing_type','BEKAS')
                            ->get('user_listing_tbl', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(5));
            return $sql->result();
```

I am still newbie at web programming, can i have inputs on which part i am lacking ? Because it works when i type example.com/mobil/bekas/toyota/avanza but it wont show anything when i type example.com/mobil/bekas/toyota

Answer (score 1):

1 ) You are passing `NULL` as a string in parameter

2) Please use the if condition base on the $model_name at the time of the database query. Do not pass the extra conditions in query with like model_name LIKE '';

```
$this->db->select('*')
    ->join('car_list_tbl','car_list_tbl.car_list_ID = user_listing_tbl.car_list_ID')
    ->join('member_tbl','member_tbl.mID = user_listing_tbl.mID')
    ->join('brand_tbl','brand_tbl.brand_name = car_list_tbl.brand_name')
    ->join('model_tbl','model_tbl.model_ID = car_list_tbl.model_ID')
    ->join('series_tbl','series_tbl.series_ID = car_list_tbl.series_ID')
    ->where('car_list_tbl.brand_name',$brand_nama);

if($model_nama){
    $this->db->like('model_tbl.model_nama', $model_nama);
}
    $this->db->where('user_listing_tbl.listing_type','BEKAS');
    ->get('user_listing_tbl', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(5));
return $this->db->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function declaration has a small syntax error. The value `NULL` is a special value in PHP and as such, should not be surrounded in quotes. For this reason, you were querying the database for the type `'toyota'` with the make `'NULL'` rather than `NULL`. 
Changing your controller code should fix the issue:

```
 public function bekas($brand_nama,$model_nama=NULL) 
 {
 //...
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but it still wont show anything if i type in example.com/mobil/bekas/toyota/

Comment: Make condition `if ($model_nama == NULL){/* just grab the $brand */} else {/* grab both */}`.